# Can I not have full-stops rendered on a websites heading/titles

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

One of my Wordpress websites is being content managed by someone who will not stop using full-stops at the end of headings/titles. I'm tired of manually following the trail.

Is there a way to have a script prevent them from being rendered. Similar to the way double spaces are not rendered?

Comment: You should be able to filter it out, this link may help: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/way-to-remove-final-dot-from-page-titles

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you can hook into the wordpress page titles, but you cant do this with other heading tags within the content. What you can do is write a little javascript. Here i am using jquery, which is included with wordpress:

```
$('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).text();
    if(title.slice(-1)=='.'){
        $(this).text(title.slice(0, -1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo str_replace(".","",$title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add a filter to your `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'removeFullstop');
function removeFullStop($title) {
    if (substr($title, -1) == '.') {
        $title = rtrim($title, ".");
    }
    return $title;
}
```

if you want to allow multiple dots at the end you need to extend the if clause by `AND substr($title, -2) != '.'`.

**Update:**
The above code actually removes the dot before it's displayed, but it will get saved to the database. So it would be better to use the following code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'removeFullstop' , '99', 2 );

function removeFullstop( $data , $postarr ) {
    if (substr($title, -1) == '.') {
        $data['post_title'] = rtrim($data['post_title'], ".");
    }
    return $data;
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Comment: The update didn't seem to work. The first one works as you said saves the dot. I can live with that.